# Using list[ ] function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

How can I get a list as a output instead of numbers printing one below the other
for my code:

```
def factors(n):


    for i in range(1, n):
        if n % i == 0:

            print(i)


prime_factors(28)
```

How can I get the output as a list

I tried:

```
def factors(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, n):
        if n % i == 0:

            lst.append(i)
        return(lst)


factors(28)
```

but this gives error

Comment: You probably want to define the list *outside* the loop, and *return* (not print) it.

Comment: Please traverse your code line by line.

Comment: I edited it as you said but its still giving me error

Answer (score 2):

The "lst" doesn't exist outside of the if scope. 
You should declare the "lst" before the if statement, and probably you want before the for. Even more you want to print the list outside the for's scope

```
def factors(n):

    lst = []
    for i in range(1, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
    print(lst)


factors(28)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two small problems in your code. You set `lst` as an empty list for every iteration of the loop and the function should probably return the list. This works:

```py
def factors(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
    return lst

print(factors(28))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what the simplified method for the list...

```
def factors(n):
    list1=[i for i in range(1,n) if n%i==0]
    print(list1)

factors(28)
```

hope it is helpful..